# Xubuntu X11VNC and Vino VNC - broken text and menus

Tags: xubuntu, vnc

Text in menus looks broken when I connect to my Ubuntu 14.04 installation via X11VNC or Vino

Image:

[image: characters missing in menus]

Comment: Possible dup of: #584922, #582980

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here worked:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

> ```
> Section "Device"
> Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
> Driver      "intel"
> Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
> EndSection
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

Updated and Optimized Open Graphics Drivers

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers
```